# How to call windows authentication programmatically in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Here is my scenario.

- When anonymous user visits site collection's default site, custom login form panel is shown. This form is a webUserControl(.ascx file) that is embeded into page as webpart.
- Then user enters username and password.
- When submit button has been clicked, authentication will be handled by code behind of custom login form panel.

Here is my question. How can I call SharePoint's authentication method with the username and password that is entered by user. Simply, I want users to login through my custom login form panel instead of  windows authentication window.

Comment: This may help... http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3622481

Comment: Nope. I dont want to use form based authentication. I just want to serve nice login panel to website users instead of default ugly window that ask for username and password.

Comment: Forms-based auth is the solution.  There's no other way around it.

Comment: How do you mean 'windows authentication window is looking really bad'? windows auth should be totally seamless. Is it that you need to expose the app to users not logged onto the domain? Or do you just need to adjust your Intranet Zone settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to have you SharePoint site use Forms Based Authentication. There is an LDAP Membership provider you can use that will authenticate against an LDAP store. Usually that is Active Directory (which is what windows authentication uses to authenticate.). There are other LDAP stores you could use too.

The only way to have a custom login form/web part is to use FBA with a custom membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you don't want to use the FBA, and want to stick to Windows authentication then your only option is to use LDAP, that will allow you to carry on with the Login Logic of WebPart and with the Windows Authentication.

Refer these links

[Link 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/harsh/archive/2007/01/10/forms-based-authentication-in-moss.aspx)

[Link 2](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/Sharepoint/94_Active_Directory_for_FBA_in_SharePoint_using_LDAP.aspx)

Comment: It is not the thing that i am looking for. I just need a SharePoint procedure that takes username and password and authenticastes user with credientials.